# Call sendSignedTransaction without waiting for result (execute in background)

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, javascript, ethereumjs

My **Vue.js** code with web3.js:

```js
function dreamOn() {
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txFin);
    return;
}
```

I want to send this transaction, but I don't want to wait for the result of sendSignedTransaction (a transaction sends for 5 seconds, it's too long). I want just do return, and the function should execute in the background. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to continue execution while the transaction runs in the background - remove the `await` keyword:

```js
function dreamOn() {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txFin);
    return;
}
```

The [`await` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in JavaScript is used to pause execution until a promise resolves. So if you don't want to pause, don't use `await`.

If you want to do something with the result once the transaction resolves, you can pass a callback function using [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
function dreamOn() {
    // Don't pause execution, but log the result once the transaction resolves
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txFin).then(console.log);
    return;
}
```